# Object from array using es6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I would like to have this object:

```
const m = {a:undefined, b:undefined, d:undefined};
```

but would prefer to produce it from an array:

```
const m = {}
const l = ["a","b","c"];
for (const i in l){
    m[l[i]] = undefined;
}
```

But what would be a nicer way of doing this when using es6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each property to an object, and combine them using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const m = Object.assign(...['a', 'b', 'c'].map((prop) => ({ [prop]: undefined })));

console.log(m);
```

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508).

Comment: It is in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: MDN is not the source of truth, the spec is. Please read the post I linked to. MDN actually changed the wording to "Spread syntax", but I guess URLs cannot be updated.

Comment: It's not only the URL. They use it in the body as well several times. The link to the article is missing, but I'll your word for it. Changed to spread syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `for/of`, but [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (which exists since ES5) might be more elegant:

```
const m = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = undefined, o), {});
```

However, if you need this a lot, I'd recommend to create a reusable function with a proper name.